# What do you call someone who decides to do something even though they know its wrong

Tags: meaning

Is there a word that described someone who decides to do something even though they know it's wrong?

Comment: [*criminal, crook, felon, lawbreaker, miscreant, misdoer,...*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sinner). I think this is Too Broad.

Comment: While I have often heard the saying "ignorance isn't a defense," knowledge of the criminal act is not inherent in the definition of criminal, or felon in my opinion.  Of all the options presented by @FumbleFingers I think "crook" or "miscreant" fit best, as they imply a willful disregard of the law.

Comment: agreed @lumberjack, you're not a criminal unless you're convicted of a crime.

Comment: Also *hypocrite*.

Comment: Your question will likely be closed without improvement.  You might want to consider adjusting your question.  In particular the word "wrong" leaves your question too broad. "What do you call someone who commits an immoral act despite his or her belief that the act is immoral?"  Or "What do you call someone who commits a crime despite knowing that his or her actions are breaking the law?"

Answer (score 1):

As a native American English speaker, I would colloquially refer to the person you described as a "rebel."

Oxford dictionary's second definition for Rebel fits my usage:

> [Rebel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rebel)
>   - A person who resists authority, control, or convention.

Another word that came to mind in the same context is "contrarian."  Oxford dictionary's first definition for Contrarian sounds like a good fit as well:

> [Contrarian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/contrarian) - A person who opposes or rejects popular opinion

If we are talking about a person who is willfully breaking the law, then "scofflaw" is a good fit.  Oxford dictionaries defines "scofflaw" as follows:

[Scofflaw](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scofflaw) - a person who flouts the law, especially by failing to comply with a law that is difficult to enforce effectively.

Comment: Certainly most "rebels" (and probably most "contrarians" too) don't "know that what they're doing is *wrong*". But per my comment/closevote, I think the question is probably unsalvageable. Much depends on what OP means by *knows, decides, wrong*, etc. - but even if we had all that, there would probably be scores of alternatives, none obviously "**the** correct answer".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree the question could be improved.  I'm not so sure it is unsalvageable, but that remains to be seen I think.  I understand what you are saying about the word "wrong" (but not so much "knows" and "decides".)  Wrong could be "immoral" or "illegal" or "unlawful" or a number of others.  Each of these might determine a different subset of answers (e.g. the "sinner" synonyms you offered up might be most appropriate for "immoral.")  If OP selected "illegal" then "scofflaw" would be a good fit.  Point being, I agree it could be improved.  I disagree that it is unsalvageable.

Comment: Well, I did say *probably* unsalvageable, which is why I didn't bother offering any guidance alongside my closevote to suggest possible improvements. There's no point in finding further fault with your two suggestions (I suppose either of them might feasibly be *exactly* right if the question were more tightly focussed), but if you think it *can* be salvaged, it might have been better to post comments asking the OP to make appropriate changes/clarifications, rather than firing off an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did make suggestions after you posted your comment.  I had no issues with the question until I read your criticisms.

Comment: Ha! You're too fast for me! I guess we'll just have to wait and see what happens next.